# Find Frequency of words and output each word-group and the frequency

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need help. I have tried this for about 2 weeks and to no avail.

I have strings of words and I want to find the frequency of each word group, print the words (doesn't matter if word appear multiple times), and the total frequency for each word group by each words.

For example, I have words as follows:

```
'abc'
'abc'
'abc'
'abc'
'xyz'
'xyz'
'tuf'
'pol'
'pol'
'pol'
'pol'
'pol'
'pol'
```

and need an output as:

```
'abc', 4
'abc', 4
'abc', 4
'abc', 4
'xyz', 2
'xyz', 2
'tuf', 1
'pol', 6
'pol', 6
'pol', 6
'pol', 6
'pol', 6
'pol', 6
```

I am using python3 and I have tried this code and it doesn't work as expected:

```
curr_tk = None                         
tk = None  
count = 0 

for items in data:
    line = items.strip()
    file = line.split(",") 
    tk = file[0]

   if curr_tk == tk:
      count += 1

   else:
      if curr_tk:
         print ('%s , %s' % (curr_tk, count))
      count = 1
      curr_tk = tk

  #print last word
  if curr_tk == tk:
      print ('%s , %s' % (curr_tk,count))
```

The above code gives me output as:

```
'abc', 4
'xyz', 2
'tuf', 1
'pol', 6
```

but that is not what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data comes from a list, then you can do the following

```
data = ['abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'xyz', 'xyz', 'tuf', 'pol', 'pol', 'pol', 'pol', 'pol', 'pol']

frequency_map = {}
for item in data:
    if item in frequency_map:
        frequency_map[item] += 1
    else:
        frequency_map[item] = 1

for item in data:
    print(f"{item}, {frequency_map[item]}")
```

And your output will be:

```
abc, 4
abc, 4
abc, 4
abc, 4
xyz, 2
xyz, 2
tuf, 1
pol, 6
pol, 6
pol, 6
pol, 6
pol, 6
pol, 6
```

You can apply the same concept to data coming from any source. For example, if your input is a string:

```
data = "'abc','abc','abc','abc','xyz','xyz','tuf','pol','pol','pol','pol','pol','pol'"

frequency_map = {}
words = data.split(',')
for item in words:
    if item in frequency_map:
        frequency_map[item] += 1
    else:
        frequency_map[item] = 1

for item in words:
    print(f"{item}, {frequency_map[item]}")
```

This is called a frequency list and it is what you are looking for here.

Comment: The data is neither in a list nor dictionary, it's just in string format as given in the question and I want to perform the operation without putting it in a list or dictionary.

Comment: The input is not clear from your question. Anyways, the same method should work with strings. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Amrsaeed, is there a way I can still without using a for loop?

Comment: Because your list is not guaranteed to be ordered and you need to count the occurrences, you need two passes through the data: one to count, and one to display. This is an O(N) implementation which is as good as it gets in terms of complexity. There will always be a for loop but you can replace the if condition with list's count function or dictionary's get function.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be something like this:

```
data = ['abc','abc','abc','abc','xyz','xyz','tuf','pol','pol','pol','pol','pol','pol']
for item in data :
    print(item, data.count(item))
```

Comment: The data is neither in a list nor dictionary, it's just in string format as given in the question and I want to perform the operation without putting it in a list or dictionary.

Comment: is there a way I can still without using a for loop?

Comment: In this case Your question is not clear. Please precise the format of the initial data.